# AngularJS form validation is always true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

`loginForm.$valid` is always return true, even when required fields are not filled out.  I was unable to find a similar problem anywhere.

```
<form name="loginForm" 
      class="form-login" 
      ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && loginCtrl.login(navCtrl)" 
      novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Username:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
    <div>Login form is {{loginForm.$valid}}</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form validation and related flags will be set only if you have `ng-model` controllers assigned to the respective controls. So assign `ng-model` directive to them. Also instead of using `id`, you could use `name`. It will then be used as alias (property names) for the respective ng-model controller assigned on the formController instance (ex: `loginForm.username.$valid` ).

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Username:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
         ng-model="ctrl.userName"
         name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
           ng-model="ctrl.password"
           name="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you; however, now the form is never valid even with both fields filled out. E: Nevermind, I wasn't entering a valid email. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. The answer was `required` syntax wasn't there.
So it was always valid to submit the form.

Comment: The example in the question is using the `required` attribute.

Comment: i know , but in my case i had this problem in angular 8 , and it was because of required syntax

Answer (score -1):

Remember.

if you are on angular 5 material design and using [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" in input field make it false ==> [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: false}"